# Doctrine2 - Entity Revisioning

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say i have an entity `Product` which has some kind of reference to entity `Invoice`.
To simplify things: Let's say an `Invoice` can only reference one `Product` (OneToOne Association).

But i can't use a simple Association, because the `Product` properties might change during usage of the application and those changes should not impact the `Invoice`.

So, everytime i want to associate an `Product` with an `Invoice`, i should clone the `Product` and have some kind of revision entity: `ProductRevision` extends `Product`. But `Product` has some other associated entities, which have to revisioned, too.

Any ideas how to implement this nicely?

Comment: Instead of extending `ProductRevision` to `Product` can't you have a one to many association between those two? I hope `product_revision` is a table.

Comment: This will result in the same problem, i tried to solve. An Association maps to a reference column. So any changes to `Product` will change `ProductRevision`, too.